# STRIDE data all years

Tags: data-request, drugs

The DEA collects data on illegal drugs and makes one year available here: http://www.dea.gov/resource-center/stride-data.shtml. I need this data for every year since 1999. What is the best way to get it?

Comment: Is it media related, or study related??

Comment: @TahirImanov study related.

Comment: send email to ODLL@usdoj.gov or just call DEA office and request a copy.